# How would a multiple sections app be built according to WPF conventions?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, conventions

I'm learning WPF, and in order to understand more about design conventions, I'd like to ask a simple question.

I'd like my UI to consist of a navigation sidebar and a main content section.
A good demonstration of my idea can be found here: https://icons8.com/wpf

As an Android developer, I know fragments were basically *built* for such design needs, however, I don't know of any WPF alternative.

With that being said, what did come to mind is to define the sidebar and the main content section as separate `UserControl`s, and then use the `MainWindow.xaml` file as the connecting point between the two.

Is that conventional though? If not, what is the most WPF-ish way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I worked on a project where we had a WPF program that contained separate "modules" (sections) for different parts of the program. The way we did it and I thought it worked really well was to have one main form, which contained a sidebar pane and a content pane. The sidebar pane was a treeview menu.

The content pain contained a tab control which we would insert UserControls into. For instance we would have a UserControl that is a payroll form, and another UserControl that displayed reports. This worked really well and allowed us to keep modules separate and organize the project. Yes, this is a pretty conventional structure (as you said you saw it in Android development, but I've also seen it in winforms and web development).

We used this fabtab control as the base for the content pane because we wanted the user to be able to access multiple tabs simultaneously: https://fabtab.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks! What really interests me is whether the sidebar pane and the content pane were both defined in one long XAML file, or was there any kind of separation to multiple files. What is the most common approach for such 'complex' UIs in WPF?

Comment: We put the content pane and sidebar pane in the main window, then the content pane would "host" UserControls. For our uses the content pane and the sidebar pane were very simple so it made sense to put them in the main window without separating them into UserControls. That said, you would not have much trouble separating the sidebar pane and content pane into separate UserControls if it gets too unwieldy, the tricky part would be the interaction between the two Controls, but that can be accomplished by passing each control a reference to the other or the parent window.

Answer (score 1):

Separated `UserControl`s or one big `MainWindow`; both will go well as long as you do not reuse separated controls. It is still a useful way to prepare dedicated view models for each separated control, rather than only one corresponding to `MainWindow`. I think there is no de-facto standard for that matter.

Comment: Thank you! Glad to hear that, but what do you mean by "as long as you do not reuse separated controls"? Aren't separate controls MEANT to be reused?

Comment: Sorry it is ambiguous. Just naturally, separated controls provide a clearer outlook of app even if you do not reuse them. It is unpleasant that the main view model possesses misc appearance properties for side controls. Matter of balancing.